# Windows forms textbox input from certain device

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have am building a win forms app which will have a text box that needs to be populated with a unique Id from an RFID tag.

The reader is recognized by windows as a keyboard device and when a tag is scanned the uid is written as If typed from a keyboard.

I need to ensure that a single textbox in my app can only take input from the RFID reader "keyboard"

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do this. if the reader is unable to scan or broken the operator will read the digits and type them in with the standard keyboard, like they do at the store when you buy something and label is not readable because twisted or so...

Comment: Thats an excellent point...however the person using the app will not have the ability to visually inspect the tag or the UID as it will be housed in an enclosure. The backup plan would be to replace the reader or try a different tag

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with exact same kind of hardware (RFID reader connected to ps2 port) in one of my previous jobs.

In your situation though, I think of 2 options:

1. You should make sure that your application is always active so that all the keyboard events are received by your form.
2. You can have a global keyboard hook so that you application will receive all the keyboard events. Check following links for global keyboard hook in C#:
    http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSLLKeyboardHook.aspx
    http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx

Once you get the keyboard events by any of the above way - you can easily direct the keys to your textbox.